# SSL Handshake failed Android 5.1

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

Since Android 5.0.2 or 5.1.1 on Samsung devices my Android app receive error message when connecting web interface of old router "FRITZ!Box 7170".

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
> ssl=0xaecc7e00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
> error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:got Channel
> ID before a ccs (external/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:3632
> 0xaf0e1679:0x00000000)

If I connect same interface with Firefox Browser:

> ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key

I think it is because of unsafe Diffie-Hellman key length?
How to avoid this? I am using `HTTPClient` to make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem.

The reason was a samsung security update, which has change a default cipher suite array given by SSLSocketFactory. Apropos if you take a nexus device with android M on it, you will see this error message

```
ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key
```

On samsung devices it is a

```
SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM
```

The **solution** for me was to override cipher suites array. Here is my SSLSocketFactory, which I use to create ssl sockets.

```
public class SpeedportSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SpeedportSSLSocketFactory.class);

/**
 * the order of ciphers in this list is important here e.g. TLS_DHE_* must not stay above TLS_RSA_*
 */
private static final String[] APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES = new String[]{
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
        "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
};

private SSLSocketFactory factory;

public SpeedportSSLSocketFactory() {
    try {
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslcontext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{
                // accepts certs with valid but expired key chain (incl. root cert)
                new ExpiredSpeedportTrustManager()}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        factory = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Cannot create SpeedportSSLSocketFactory", ex);
    }
}

// dirty
private void injectHostname(InetAddress address, String host) {
    try {
        Field field = InetAddress.class.getDeclaredField("hostName");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(address, host);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        logger.error("Cannot inject hostName");
    }
}

public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
    return new SpeedportSSLSocketFactory();
}

public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return factory.createSocket();
}

public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return factory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

public Socket createSocket(InetAddress addr, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return factory.createSocket(addr, port, localAddr, localPort);
}

public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i) throws IOException {
    return factory.createSocket(inaddr, i);
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return factory.createSocket(host, port, localAddr, localPort);
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {

    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    injectHostname(addr, host);

    Socket socket = factory.createSocket(addr, port);
    ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(getSupportedCipherSuites());
    return socket;
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES;
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return APPROVED_CIPHER_SUITES;
}
```

}

Last two methods override default cipher suite. I am not sure, what you need override both.

The order in cipher suites array is also **very important**